# Why the difference in chi square contingency table values?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have a 2x2 contingency table and would like to compute p-values for the chi square test using python. The table in question, and the values I calculated manually are:

Observed

```
          |Infected  | Not infected|
----------| -------- | --------    |
Placebo   | 20       | 21          |
Rimatidine| 1        | 34          |
```

Expected

```
          | Infected | Not infected |
----------| -------- | --------     |
Placebo   | 11.5     | 29.5         |
Rimatidine| 9.5      | 25.5         |

x^2 = 19.7
p = 9e-6 using integral from 19.7 to infinity (1/sqrt(2pi))*x^-0.5 * e^-0.5x dx
```

I got this instead:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

data = np.array([[20, 21], [1, 34]])
```

Results:

```
Chi2ContingencyResult(statistic=17.683283406488982, pvalue=2.6090948664138648e-05, dof=1, expected_freq=array([[11.32894737, 29.67105263], [ 9.67105263, 25.32894737]]))
```

Is this the correct function to use? What formula can I use to compute the values manually?

Comment: you can look at the source code here https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/stats/contingency.py#L90-L135, to understand how the expected_freq is computed.